# Calling Swift from Objective C, closure to block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I started converting an Objective c project to Swift.
First thing I am converting is the network layer.
I'm trying to write my network layer in Swift in a way that it can be called from objective c.

The problem is in my swift code I'm passing closures to a method. It works in Swift, but doesn't seem like when generating header files it generates method definition for any method that is using closures?

Is there a workaround for this, or any way where I could have a swift method that takes a closure/block?

**Swift class**

```
@objc public class UserNetworkManager: BaseNetworkManager {

   // I can call this from objective c
   public func fetchSomething() {

   }

   // I can't call this from objective c
   public func fetchFriends(userId: String, completion: ([User]?, NSError?)->()) -> Request {

   }

}
```

**Generated Header**

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC12Company19UserNetworkManager")
@interface UserNetworkManager : BaseNetworkManager
- (void)fetchSomething;
@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue converting your closure to a block as long as every type involved can be translated to Objective-C. In this case, it's likely that you haven't tagged your User and Request classes as `@objc`, which would prevent this method from being generated.

Comment: Perfect, the Request object was not marked with @objc. The problem is that is not a part of my app that is from Alamofire library. I'm wondering If I can create a wrapper and send it back to controller in case request needs to be canceled

Answer (score -1):

To instantiate an Objective-C class in Swift, you call one of its initializers using Swift initializer syntax.

Objective-C initializers begin with **init**, or **initWith**: if the initializer takes one or more arguments. When an Objective-C initializer is imported by Swift, the **init** prefix becomes an init keyword to indicate that the method is a Swift initializer. If the initializer takes an argument, the With is removed and the rest of the selector is divided up into named parameters accordingly.